# return top N rows and have remaining rows rolled up into a single row - oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate-functions, summary

I am trying to get a result set with the top N rows from the query, and have the remaining rows rolled up into a single row. I have come up with a query as below - i am needing suggestions about using any built-in oracle sql functions that can help with this scenario and eliminate a lot of the redundancy i have in this sql.

```
    select label, count_id from 
(
select table1.NAME as label, count(table1.id) as count_id, 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by  count(table1.id) desc) AS rn  
      from table1 
      where table1.NAME like 'D%'
      group by table1.NAME
      )
      where rn <= 9  -- get top 9 rows
union

select 'Other' as label, sum(count_id) as count_id from 
(
select label, count_id from 
(
select table1.NAME as label, count(table1.id) as count_id, 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by  count(table1.id) desc) AS rn  
      from table1 
      where table1.NAME like 'D%'
      group by table1.NAME
      )
      where rn > 9 -- get rows after row-num 9
 )
```

please share if you have any suggestions on improving this query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a textbook case for illustrating [subquery refactoring](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_10002.htm#sthref9758).

Here are my suggestions:

```
WITH q AS
(
SELECT table1.NAME AS label, COUNT(table1.id) AS count_id, 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(table1.id) DESC) AS rn  
  FROM table1 
 WHERE table1.name LIKE 'D%'
 GROUP BY table1.name
)
SELECT label, count_id FROM q WHERE rn <= 9
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Other' AS label, SUM(count_id) AS count_id 
  FROM q
 WHERE rn > 9 
 GROUP BY 'Other';
```

On the table in my database I tried this on I actually got a cost improvement as well - YMMV.

Comment: I like the use of the WITH block.  Very appropriate in this instance.  One minor improvement... you should switch your UNION to a UNION ALL since there won't be duplicates between the 2 sets.

Comment: True enough generically, although there are only 10 rows total in this case.

Comment: @Craig @DCookie thank you very much for your suggestions - and the details about associated query costs.

Answer (score 2):

Another variation on @DCookie's answer to try:

```
WITH
q as ( 
    select
        table1.name as label,
        count(table1.id) as count_id,        
        row_number() over (order by count(table1.id) desc) as rn    
    from table1   
    where table1.name like 'D%'  
    group by table1.name
)
select
    case
        when rn <= 9
        then label
        else 'Other'
    end label,
    sum(count_id) count_id
from q
group by
    case
        when rn <= 9
        then label
        else 'Other'
    end;
```

Comment: +1 for avoiding the UNION. Interestingly enough, this way has the same total cost as the original query - I don't see the cost improvement.